# Sed - Delete x numbers of characters before a string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line, sed

I have a txt file and I want to delete x number of characters before a specific string

Example :

```
52.451878252 foo 845.851878212 foo
98.444854655 foo 458.344854656 foo
```

I want to delete 8 characters before the string ' foo' in order to get this :

```
52.45 foo 845.66 foo
98.44 foo 458.66 foo
```

How should I do with the sed command (or something else) ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sed -e 's/........foo/ foo/g' file.txt
```

Or equivalently:

```
sed -e 's/.\{8\}foo/ foo/g' file.txt
```

Or even:

```
sed -e 's/.\{8\}\(foo\)/ \1/g' file.txt
```

Or a different approach, with the same output for your sample:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{7\} / /g' file.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! Quick and efficient. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to round each float down to the second decimal point, you could use `printf`.

```
while read line; do
    printf "%0.2f %s %0.2f %s\n" $line
done < file.txt
```

Comment: This is genius. Because I have a ton of KML files with coordinates way too long. Now I can round these coordinates. Thank you sire.